# Connection to Access 2013 (64 bit) using Java 8 on Netbeans (64 bit)

Tags: java, odbc, database-connection, java-8, ms-access-2013

I've been unable to connect my Java program to my MS Access Database. The database file is in my Netbeans project folder under the name PhonesDatabase.accdb . 
This is the error I am receiving:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Any feedback would be appreciated.
The following is my current code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DB {

private static Connection conn = null;

public DB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,         *.accdb)};DBQ=" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\PhonesDatabase.accdb");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }


}

ResultSet queryTbl (String sqlStmt) throws SQLException
{
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
return rs;
}//end queryTbl

void updateTbl (String update) throws SQLException
{
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(update);
stmt.close();
}//end updateTbl
}//end DB class
```

Thanks NF

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: public DB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,         *.accdb)};DBQ=" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\PhonesDatabase.accdb");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }


}

Comment: i.e. my catch statement returns "Error"

Comment: What does `System.getProperty("java.version")` return?

Comment: I solved the issue. JDK 8 doesn't support that database driver. If anyone else had a similar issue, you must down grade to JDK 7. Thanks for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)